# PrimeFaces, Disabling/Enabling an p:inputText does not save its value to database

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm combining a `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` and a `<p:inputText>`. The `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`´s value must be enabled/disabled the `<p:inputText>`. When `<p:inputText>` is enabled (`<p:inputText>` property `disabled=false`) the user is allowed to type a value to the input text field to later it be saved to a Database ( both values, checkBox and inputText). Everything is working fine, except that the value introduced to the inpuText object is not saved to data base. I'm using a PestgreSQL database, field `dpNumPasaporte` in database is numeric.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkPasaporte" 
                         value="#{DatosPersonalesBean.chkPasaporte}" 
                         style="float: right;padding-top: 9px;" >
                <p:ajax  event="change"
                         update="inpPasaporte"/> 
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:inputText id="inpPasaporte" 
             value="#DatosPersonalesBean.datosPersonales.dpNumPasaporte}" 
             style="alignment-adjust: baseline; width: 190px"
             disabled="#{!(DatosPersonalesBean.chkPasaporte)}">
</p:inputText>
```

Note: I tested the block `<p:inputText>` separately and it is saving in database.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Bear in mind that components with `disabled="true"` will not get processed  during a request

Comment: Hi there. To really analyze your problem without guessing around, it would be great if you provided the ManagedBean and the whole form you are using to process the values. How is the form submitted?

Answer (score -1):

you must add an ajax event and I think that you have missed by entering the name of your Bean, you must add :

```
<p:inputText ... value="#{datosPersonalesBean.datosPersonales.dpNumPasaporte}` >
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Abed. I just added an ajax according to your suggestion, but still without no work.

Comment: how did you save your Value, can you write the function please ?